# App incorrectly starting with non-launcher activity

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I'm developing an Android app consisting of a `MainActivity` (launcher activity), a number of other `activities`, a couple of `intent services` and custom Application class for storing app-wide data.

The app startup procedure is:

1. The launcher **`activity MainActivity`** starts
2. If the `data` in the custom Application `class` is uninitialized, `MainActivity` initializes the data in the custom Application class based on persistently stored data and whether user is logged in (I use Firebase for authentication)
3. `MainActivity` prints some stuff in the `log`
4. `MainActivity` starts one of the other `activities` and calls `finish()` to terminate itself.

I encountered the following problem:

5. With my device connected via USB I started the app from Android Studio and navigated among the "other" `activities`, everything worked fine.
6. I disconnected the device from USB and used other apps on the device for about an hour. The `activity` last shown by the app was `GameListActivity`
7. I started my app by clicking its icon on the device screen. The app crashed during starup.
8. I connected the device to USB and retrieved some `logs`.

In the logs I could see that the crash happened because `GameListActivity` accessed an uninitialized object in the custom `Application class`. The following lines from the log seem interesting:

```
10-15 21:13:42.515 1410-2915/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.xxx.game3/.MainActivity bnds=[282,812][540,1110]} from uid 10107 on display 0
10-15 21:13:42.584 1410-2907/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 20722:com.xxx.game3/u0a313 for activity com.xxx.game3/.GameListActivity
```

It seems the `MainActivity` was launched and immediately after that `GameListActivity` was started. But the log printout described in 3 above is not present and there is no way the `MainActivity` could start `GameListActivity` without first doing the log printout. (I'm assuming the log is completely reliable)

Also, some time before I started the app the second time in 7 above, this was logged:

```
10-15 21:03:13.163 1410-26164/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.xxx.game3 (pid 30877) has died
```

Does this indicate an error or does it simply mean that Android has killed the process for my app in order to free up system resources?

Could the fact that I started the app first from Android Studio and then by clicking the icon on the device somehow mess things up?

Could it be that the Android system somehow started `GameListActivity` instead of `MainActivity`?

EDIT: added **`Manifest`** file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.xxx.game3">

    <application
        android:name=".GameApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".GameListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game_list"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.xxx.game3.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".NetworkService"/>
        <service android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".NotificationService"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".NetworkListener"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".SignOutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_out"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NewGameActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game"
            android:parentActivityName=".GameListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.xxx.game3.GameListActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName=".GameListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.xxx.game3.GameListActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InvitePlayerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_invite_player"
            android:parentActivityName=".GameActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.xxx.game3.GameActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HandleInviteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_handle_invite"
            android:parentActivityName=".GameListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.xxx.game3.GameListActivity"/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: If you give the name of custom application class to `name` attribute of `application` element in manifest file properly then in any activity `getApplication()` will return your custom application object. So it is never the case *If the custom Application class is uninitialized* in point number 2. BTW if there is an application component running then there must be the application object to hold the application component.

Comment: you *can't* finish launch activity. It may lead to crashes. Regarding reading the log, make sure that you selected the connected device in Android Monitor and the type is verbose with no searched keyboards. `Show only selected application` should also be selected..

Comment: @adnan9011 - added Manifest file to question

Comment: @Birendra - Thanks, I realized I was a bit unclear: MainActivity initializes data in the custom Application class, not the custom Application class itself. The name of the application class is equal to the name attribute. I editied the question to clarify this.

Comment: @samirk433 - I'm not sure this explains it... in the second startup, the crash happened before the MainActivity ever got to starting GameListActivity and then finishing itself. I'll look into it anyway. Thanks

Comment: @Aardvark I don't think finishing MainActivity is a problem. I feel that the condition you used for checking if objects in the custom Application class are initialized is the culprit.

Comment: My resoning was that I need to handle the follwing startup scenarios:

1. No application components running: MainActivity starts and initializes data in the custom Application class.
2. All activities destroyed but data in the custom application class is initialized (for example if one or both of the services is running): MainActivity starts but does not initialize data in the custom Application class.
3. One of the activities in stopped or paused state. data in the custom Application class already initialized. The stopped/paused activity is resumed, MainActivity not involved.

Comment: Even if I made an error in the initialization logic, I should still be able to see the log printout from MainActivity before it starts the GameListActivity.

I will be careful to not have any log filters active as pointed out by samirk433 if i manage to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of launcher activity was wrong. Even if all components have been destroyed and android has killed the application process, it cannot be assumed that the next launch of the application will be done via the launcher (my `MainActivity`) activity. Android may restore the application in the last activity in the previous session.

I guess this means that I need to check if the initialization sequence needs to be run in `OnCreate()` in all my activities and if it does, launch the `MainActivity` (which will handle initialization) and finish the activity being started.

Found the answer here: http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/

Thanks for the answers